# Prove Satisfiability of Property by Set

Tags: proof-writing

What is a proof strategy for proving that some property is satisfied by a particular set of numbers.

For example, what would be an approach for proving that the [archimedean property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) is satisfied by the rational numbers?
In the context I'm coming from ([Apostol's Calculus book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471000051)), the archimedean  property is presented as follows:

> For all real ${a,x,y}$, if ${a \le x < a+y/n}$ for all positive
>   integers $n$, then ${a=x}$.

Answer (score 4):

You need only provide a direct proof, showing that the rationals satisfy, by *definition*, the Archimedean Property.

Many, many proofs you'll encounter "fall-out" directly from definitions: what does it mean for $x, y$ to be rational numbers? (Definition). What does it mean to say that a particular set of numbers satisfies the Archimedean Property? (Definition).

Comment: Given the context I provided, I don't see how, by definition, the rationals satisfy the archimedean property.

Comment: I mean use how we define the rationals, and then given the definition of the Archimedean Property, your proof is simply a *verification* that the rationals satisfy the property: write out what being Archimedean *means* & what being rational *means* & verify the latter satisfies the former.

Comment: @amWhy: You are an answering machine! :-) +1

Comment: @amWhy: I'm trying to prove that there is no implication from the archimedean property that there are real numbers which are not rational, are we on the same page?

Comment: That wasn't the question you posted! Sorry if I misunderstood. Perhaps post a separate question to that effect, keeping this thread, but starting a new post. I'd like to see you elaborate on what you are hoping to establish! ;-)

Comment: I thought that was the meaning of my question. :( My question was based on an exercise in Apostol's book. Now I'm not certain my understanding of the terminology is correct.

I did not understand "is satisfied by the rational numbers" to mean "is true of the rational numbers"; I understood it to mean "no reals beyond the rationals are needed for the property hold". 

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Actually, it should be understood as follows: "is satisfied by the rational numbers" should be taken to mean "is true for all rational numbers." If the question were "show that the property is satisfied **only** by the rationals", then you're take would be correct. Feel free to accept the answer ;-). We can discuss this more in comments, or in chat, or you can post a different question, if you need to.

Comment: I'd love to chat whenever you're up to it: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9178/satisfiability

Answer (score 1):

In this case a very direct strategy by just wrinting down what Archimedean means and what a rational number is should unavoidably lead to the goal.

Comment: Given the context I provided, I don't see how, by definition, the rationals satisfy the archimedean property.

Answer (score 0):

We will instead prove its contrapositive:

> For all rational numbers $a,x,y$, if $a\ne x$, then $x<a$ or there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $x \ge a+y/n$.

Choose any $a,x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a \ne x$. Now consider $x$. Observe that if $x<a$, then we are done. Thus since $a \ne x$, we may assume that $x>a$. Hence, since $x-a>0$, notice that:
$$ x \ge a+y/n \iff x-a \ge y/n \iff n(x-a) \ge y \iff n \ge \dfrac{y}{x-a}$$
Since $a,x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$ and since $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed under subtraction and (nonzero) division, we know that $\dfrac{y}{x-a} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Hence, by the definition of a rational number, it suffices to prove that for any integers $p,q$ (where $q > 0$), there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $n \ge \dfrac{p}{q}$. There are two cases to consider.

**Case 1:** If $p<0$, then $\dfrac{p}{q} < \dfrac{0}{q} =0\le 1$, so we can choose the positive integer $n=1$.

**Case 2:** Otherwise, if $p \ge 0$, then $\dfrac{p}{q} \le \dfrac{p}{1}=p < p+1$, so we can choose the positive integer $n=p+1$.

Comment: You are proving "For all rational a,x,y, if a≤x<a+y/n for all positive integers n, then a=x." I'm trying to show that there is no implication from the archimedean property that there are real numbers which are not rational.